# T4 Text Transform template creating xx.cs file avoid ErrorGeneratingOutput

Tags: t4, css

I have a t4 template that is outputting to a specified file name.  t4 however when run is creating a xx.cs file for each tt file that I have.  Within this file is the text "ErrorGeneratingOutput"

Is there a way to prevent this file from being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not, no.

When using one of the mechanisms to create specific files, there will always be a dummy stub file.
Typically I set it to be a text file with

<#@ output extension=".stub.txt" #>
and put some explanatory text in it to the effect that it's a placeholder by putting that text as the body of the template.  I then set its build action to 'None' permanently.

I'm not sure what's causing the error, but that's where any error in the rest of your template would get reported typically.

Comment: Oddly, I have used this approach in prior t4 templates but today it is not working.  Not sure why.  I have used 
<#@ output extension=".ignore" #>

There has got to be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent the erroneous generated .cs file from compiling until you are finished writing you t4 file, you can set the Build Action property for the .cs file to None and then set it back when you're done